# How to query date between in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, date-range

I have a set of records in my Mongo database.

```
2023-09-12T00:10:17.558+00:00
2023-09-12T00:10:45.515+00:00
2023-09-12T00:10:49.121+00:00
2023-09-12T00:12:59.252+00:00
2023-09-12T23:23:45.238+00:00
2023-09-12T23:23:46.170+00:00
2023-09-12T23:34:43.082+00:00
2023-09-13T06:40:37.457+00:00
```

I'm querying it using the Mongoose find

```
const findActivityLogsByFilter = async (filter: TEmployeeFilter, currentUser: IEmployeeAttributes) => {
  try {
    console.log(filter.startDate, filter.endDate);
    return await employee_activity_logsModel
      .find({
        employeeId: filter.employeeId,
        activity: { $in: filter.actions },
        logDate: { $gte: filter.startDate, $lte: filter.endDate },
        _discontinuedUser: null,
      })
      .sort({ _id: 'desc' })
      .exec();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new InternalServerError(messages.generalMessage.Error);
  }
};
```

All the records are shown if I leave the `employeeId` and `activity` alone in the filter. But when I put the `logDate` filter. there is no result showing

I tried different date formats such as

```
fromDate: 2023-09-12, toDate: 2023-09-12
```

```
fromDate: Tue Sep 12 2023 16:04:46 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time),
toDate: Tue Sep 12 2023 16:04:46 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)
```

and even use `moment` to format the date to use on the `from` and `to` date filter but there is no result shown.

I also tried to query it directly on the MongoDB Compass but had no luck.

```
{
  employeeId:ObjectId('64f9731b4f8f4f269a44e7af'), 
  logDate:{
    $gte:ISODate('2023-09-12'),
    $lte:ISODate('2023-09-12')
  }
}
```

Is there a format of date I need to use in order to query the date regardless of time? What I'm expecting is to get all the records with the date 2023-09-12 because my query is `fromDate: 2023-09-12, toDate: 2023-09-12`.

Comment: Is `logDate` of `Date` type in mongodb? Can you verify that?

Comment: Hi Robin, Yes It is. This is my schema `const EmployeeActivityLogsSchema = new Schema({
  sessionId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    default: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
  },
  employeeId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'Employee',
  },
  activity: { type: String, enum: Object.values(constants.activityActions), required: true },
  logDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true },
}).add(BaseSchema);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you filter the document with the dates with `startDate: new Date("2023-09-12")` and `endDate: new Date("2023-09-12")` with the query:

```
logDate: { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate }
```

The query will filter the document with `logDate` within "2023-09-12T00:00:00Z" to  "2023-09-12T00:00:00Z". This will only match the documents with `logDate: "2023-09-12T00:00:00Z"`.

You should add 1 day to the `endDate` and use the `$lt`:

```
filter.endDate.setDate(filter.endDate.getDate() + 1);
```

```
logDate: { $gte: filter.startDate, $lt: filter.endDate }
```

Hence the query results will become

```
logDate: { $gte: new Date("2023-09-12"), $lt: new Date("2023-09-13") }
```

to get the documents with `logDate` is on "2023-09-12".

Comment: Hi Yong. Will try your solution and update in the comment if this succeed

Comment: [Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xHLh45UTqKY)

Comment: Great! It works as expected. My bad, I did not check the time that is formatted by the `new Date("2023-09-12")`

Comment: Since this answer solved your problem you should accept and upvote it

Comment: Yes, I already gave an upvote and accepted it as solution to my question :)